# Quick query about dict mapping from a file

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I am an amature programmer. I have a quick question. How can I open a file and print out the contents of the file in a dict format?

For example:

My_file contains:

```
Hello Bye five 98 G mail
```

the output I was looking for is :

```
{details: 'Hello', 'Bye', 'five', 98, 'G', 'mail'}
```

I know how to create a dictionary and even map items to elements... but I am having trouble mapping elements from a file

Comment: your output isn't a valid python dictionary, so...

Comment: In that format, you can't.  Perhaps you meant `{"details": ['Hello', 'Bye', 'five', 98, 'G', 'mail']}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have it in that format because that isn't a valid Python dictionary.  The syntax is incorrect and `details` is undefined.

The closest you can get is:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as myfile:
    print({"details" : myfile.read().split()})
```

Output:

```
{'details': ['Hello', 'Bye', 'five', '98', 'G', 'mail']}
```

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

If you have a file like this (multiple lines):

```
Hello
Bye
five
98
G
mail
```

You can print the lines one-by-one like so:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
Hello
Bye
five
98
G
mail
```